# What is a typical reggaeton beat called?

Tags: terminology, drums

While listening to [this reggaeton song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOWMByXN33w), I was wondering if there is a specific name for such a beat, like western techno songs typical have a 4/4 beat.

Comment: If you mean *time signature* (which is what 4/4 is) - I think that song could also be 4/4..?

Comment: @topomorto I think asker is referring to the percussion sequence and rhythm, nor the time signature. Like the kick-hat-snare-hat-kick-hat-snare-hat in dance music. Listen to the linked song at around 1:55. That percussion rhythm is used in like 90% of reggaeton songs.

Answer (score 5):

4/4 isn't really a specific name for a beat - it's a *time signature* that can apply to quite a range of rhythms, including most techno, rock, and reggae beats (*Four-to-the-floor* is a slightly more specific term that is often used for techno, meaning that the bass drum is hit on each measure).

For most dance genres, the name of the genre is also an appropriate name for the rhythm, so you can just call it the "reggaeton rhythm". Another name that would be appropriate for many reggaeton songs' backings would be the "dembow" rhythm, named after the riddim used originally used for Gregory Peck's *[Poco Man Jam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnAppiW-hmc)*, but popularised by Shabba Ranks' song *[Dembow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQqwea8ZSbk)*, and widely credited as being the rhythmic foundation of the reggaeton genre.

Comment: Four-to-the-floor is actually from 50s jazz.

Comment: nop, thats wrong. Im spanish and long years follower of this movement,
Dembow is a faster rhythm than reggaeton and a different genre. Reggaeton was first.

Reggaeton: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmKAn1MeB04
Dembow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ce5sdKxpE3s

Answer (score 1):

As @User16 noted, the characteristic stuttering heartbeat rhythm of Reggaeton is called [*dembow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dembow), after the song that initially popularized it, Shabba Ranks' (infamously homophobic) reggae dancehall hit *Dem Bow*.

*Dembow*, also called *dembo,* has become a very popular and influential rhythm around the world.  It has even made its way into mainstream American pop hits such as Justin Bieber's ["Sorry."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRh_vgS2dFE)

Comment: nop, thats wrong. Im spanish and long years follower of this movement,
Dembow is a faster rhythm than reggaeton and a different genre. Reggaeton was first.

Reggaeton: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmKAn1MeB04
Dembow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ce5sdKxpE3s

Answer (score 0):

The common 3-over-4 rhythm that backs reggaeton (more precisely a 3/8+3/8+2/8 laid over a 2/4 bass beat) can be referred to as *dembow*, but that term refers more to an entire musical style.  The rhythm itself is the first measure of a common 2-measure Afro-cuban *clave* pattern.